# How to run codeml (aaml) from Biopython?

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to find dN/ds values for a bunch of amino acid sequences in a phylogenetic tree using the aaml part of codeml in BioPython. Unfortunately, I get an error when running it (results file is empty).

```
from Bio.Phylo.PAML import codeml
cml = codeml.Codeml(alignment = "family.phy", tree = "family.phy_phyml_tree.txt", out_file = "results.out")
cml.read_ctl_file("aaml.ctl")
cml.alignment = "family.phy"
cml.tree = "family.phy_phyml_tree.txt"
cml.out_file = "results.out"
results=cml.run()
```

And the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
cml.run()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\PAML\codeml.py", line 189, in run
results = read(self.out_file)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\PAML\codeml.py", line 210, in read
raise ValueError("Invalid results file")
ValueError: Invalid results file
```

Has anybody got this to work for them?

Comment: That error is only raised if the results could not be parsed at all. What is contained in your `results.out` file? Does that same control file work when you run codeml outside of Biopython? It's possible that I haven't implemented proper parsing of aaml output in `Bio.Phylo.PAML` though the parser should at least pick up some of the usual codeml detritus.

Comment: I've had this error various times, and there are various causes. For me to help you show me what your sequence (alignment/phylip/nuc) file looks like and your .ctl file. Also show me how your files are arranged (the paths)